# Migrate as separate files

Tags: 7, migrations

**How can I create individual migration groups - one for each XLM file, without having to write a new migration class for each file?**

I have dozens of XML files waiting to be imported into Drupal using the Migrate module and API.

Currently, all my migrations are registered under a single group called *Questions* as shown below:
[image]
That single group of *222* imports represents 5/6 of my XML files. If I import the pending dozens of XML files, I will have upwards of 10,000 imports.

What I would rather have is each XML file having it's own individual group.
That way I can revert a single XML file where necessary instead of all them.

Can anyone help me with this scenario?

Comment: Commenting after I answer: why would you need each migration in its own group? If the `Questions` group has, say, 10 migrations in it, each representing a single XML file, you can migrate or roll back either the whole group or an individual migration within the group. I'm not sure what splitting your one group into a bunch of smaller groups does for you.

Comment: That questions group combines multiple xml files. My purpose is to have a distinct migration group for each xml file. That way I can roll back an individual xml file where necessary instead of rolling back all the files

Comment: So in your ideal scenario, how many migration configurations would there be per group? Just one for the one file?

Comment: Ah, gotcha. My migration knowledge is limited to D8. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: this answer is probably fine for D8 but not D7.

Using the [migrate_plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus) module, I was able to specify shared configuration for about a dozen different feeds that needed to be given separate taxonomies upon import based on which organization's media I was importing. I created a group with my `source` and `process` configuration, then created individual importers for each feed with just the configuration that was specific to that feed. If I wanted to import them all at once I could run `drush mi --group=<group_name>`, and if I wanted to roll back a single feed I could run `drush migrate-rollback <migration_name>`. The only tedious part for me was creating a dozen nearly-identical migrations.

So, for example, here's a group definition for an Twitter importer:

```
id: twitter_importer
source_type: twitter
shared_configuration:
  source:
    plugin: url
    data_fetcher_plugin: http
    data_parser_plugin: json
    authentication:
      plugin: oauth2
      base_uri: 'https://api.twitter.com'
      token_url: /oauth2/token
      grant_type: client_credentials
    fields:
      -
        name: id
        selector: id_str
      -
        name: text
        selector: text
      -
        name: timestamp
        selector: created_at
    ids:
      id:
        type: string
  process:
    title:
      plugin: substr
      source: caption
      start: 0
      length: 254
    type:
      plugin: default_value
      default_value: twitter_feed_item
    # etc. etc.
```

Then a few migrations like this:

```
id: tw_dept_a
dependencies:
  - migrate
  - migrate_plus
migration_group: twitter_importer
source:
  # this changes from migration to migration
  urls: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=tmountjr&count=10'
process:
  field_source:
    # this also changes; works because the group's shared config specifies the plugin
    default_value: tmountjr
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
```

It's annoying setting it all up on the frontend but after the third one you get pretty quick at copy/pasting the template and replacing one or two variables.

So I guess to answer your question:

> How can I create individual migration groups - one for each XLM file, without having to write a new migration class for each file?

I'm not sure you can get around that...but you can abstract a lot of the repeated configuration out of each individual file using shared configurations. You can maybe further refine the process by having a template file with placeholder variables, duplicating the file, and using `sed` on the new file to replace filenames:

```
cp migration_template.yml migrate_plus.migration.migrate_xml1.yml
sed -i "s/filenameplaceholder/file1\.xml/g" migrate_plus.migration.migrate_xml1.yml
```

Comment: I'm very sorry. I should have indicated I am working in Drupal 7.
Thanks for your answer and I apologise for not specifying the version.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is to use `registerMigration` as described here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1824884

Once upon a time the D7 migration classes supported a `DynamicMigration` class which is now obsolete: https://www.drupal.org/node/2471206

But the idea is that per XML file you would do something like:

```
foreach ($xml_files as $file) {
  MigrationBase::registerMigration(
  'ExampleUserMigration',
  'ExampleUser',
   array(
      'group_name' => 'example',
      'default_uid' => 1, 
      'my_source_file' => $file)
  );
}
```

And your migration would examine the passed in custom `my_source_file` migration argument and set the migration to use that specific file.

The above code could simply be a simple php script you call using Drush for example to "register" your migrations.

**EDIT**

Dynamic migrations are still supported somewhat in D8 via:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/building-dynamic-migrations